# Rotate Animation is showing some delay in every rotation

Tags: image-rotation

Please suggest me the answer here is my code.

```
    Rotate Animation rotate = new Rotate Animation(0, 360,    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.computeDurationHint();
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setDuration(durationsecs);
    rotate.setStartOffset(-1);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    mIV_BloodPumpSpeed.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: rotation is not smooth

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please be more specific. Also, please update the tags (you're using C++, aren't you?).

Answer (score 0):

```
private RotateAnimation setRotatedAnimation(Context context, float pivotX,
            float pivotY, int duration) {
        RotateAnimation rotated = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivotX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                pivotY);
        rotated.setInterpolator(context, android.R.anim.cycle_interpolator);
        rotated.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        rotated.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotated.setDuration(duration);
        return rotated;
    }
```